# How to deploy angular-cli app on Websphere?

Tags: angular, websphere

I have simple angular 7 app.I made production Build  with ng build -- href .once the build is done we placed the dist folder to the server location. application works fine but when i refresh the application the server(WebSphere) is not able to get the routing path of the application.it works fine only when we redirect to index.html

Angular side i have used Routing Strategies as given below .

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: Refer this link for angular server deploy config https://arjunphp.com/deploy-angular-app-production-nginx/

Comment: thanks @SayanSamanta for the link but the issue we are facing is. i'm able to run the same application in IIS by specifying the (<action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />) in web config file  but the same doesn't  work with web sphere .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the web.xml file in WebSphere with the below error status code.Mention the path of deployed angular application.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/path/sampleapp/index.html</location>
</error-page>
```